# Prove the solutions of ODE are orthogonal

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonality

Consider the equation

$$
y^{\prime \prime}-x^2 y+n y=0 \tag{1}
$$

where n is a positive integer. Let $\left\{h_n\right\}_{n=1, \ldots, N}$ be a set of particular solutions of (1). Assume they obey
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow \pm \infty}\left(h_{n_1}^{\prime}(x) h_{n_2}(x)-h_{n_1}(x) h_{n_2}^{\prime}(x)\right)=0,
$$
for $n_1, n_2 \in\{1, \ldots, N\}, n_1 \neq n_2$. Here $h_{n_1}$ (respectively $h_{n_2}$ ) is a particular solution of (1) with $n=n_1$ (respectively with $n=n_2$ ). Prove
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_{n_1}(x) h_{n_2}(x) d x=0 .
$$
Moreover, assume for $n \in\{1, \ldots, N\}$ the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_n(x) h_n(x) d x=I_n,
$$
is finite for $n=1, \ldots, N$. Prove that $h_1, h_2, \ldots, h_N$ are linearly independent.

I tried to use common orthogonal functions like sin to be (1)'s particular solution but failed, any idea for proving will be appreciated.

Comment: For a symmetric matrix and its eigenvalues you prove this using $n_1(v_1^Tv_2)=v_1^TAv_2=n_2(v_1^Tv_2)$. So prove the operator is self-adjoint,...

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry I have just finished undergraduate ODE class,I don't know how to prove self-adjoint and thanks for your idea.

Comment: It practically amounts to partial integration to prove $v·L[y]=L[v]·y$ with $L[y](x)=y''(x)-x^2y(x)$, in $L^2$ scalar products, where also the Wronski conditions should find their place.

Comment: Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be solutions to (1), for $n=n_1$ and $n=n_2$. Multiply the first equation by $y_2$ and the second by $y_1$, then subtract and integrate- this will show the orthogonality. Then evaluate the Wronskian $W(y_1,y_2)$ to show linear independence